# How to convert information displayed on google map to list using php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-places-api

Hello i am trying to create a nearest places search form, that generates information that would be displayed on a map based on the locations i have in my database.

i found a very useful tutorial at here https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3, and this displays the locations on a map as wanted.

but now i want to take it a step further, and display those information on the map as a list. obviously by echoing the locations, but i have no idea how display them in that way.

this is what i have done

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;
    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }
   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }
   function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;
     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);
   }
   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations(); 
     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'engine.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function parseXml(str) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
      } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
      }
    }
    function doNothing() {}
    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onLoad="load()"> 
    <div>
    <textarea cols="25" rows="6" id="addressInput"></textarea>
    <select id="radiusSelect">
      <option value="4" selected>4mi</option>
      <option value="100">100mi</option>
      <option value="200">200mi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onClick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my server side code that does the query

```
<?php  
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('vitafoam', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();


?>
```

please how can i make this information come out in a list thanks any reply will be useful

Comment: The is currently creating a dropdown list containing all the results on that page (`<select id="locationSelect"`), created by the `createOption` function.  Do you want to change that to an unordered list and put it in a sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Where you're currently looping over the XML `marker` nodes, amend that to output to a list.  I'm not 100% sure what you mean by a list... a `<ul />`, a textarea, a comma-separated list of addresses, something else?

```
var list = '';

for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
    var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
    list += name + ', ' + address + ', ' + distance + ';';
}

document.getElementById('yourList').innerHTML = list;
```